# Spark streaming aggregate stream is not updating when reading from new csv files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run some basic examples of Spark streaming via pyspark and the behavior of the latest version (3.0.1) is not as advertised and not as I remembered it from previous versions.

Specifically, I set up a streaming DF to read csv files from a folder. Each file contains two columns: stock and value and a series of randomly generated stock values for 4 different stocks. For example:

| stock | value |
| --- | --- |
| HPE | 11.7014 |
| NHPI | 0.00672 |
| NHPI | 0.00714 |
| NHPI | 0.008232 |
| TSLA | 337.9674 |

I then groupBy the stock name and average the price.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StockTicker") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame creating a stream from incoming csv files
#Define schema
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

schema = StructType().add('stock','string').add('value','double')
dfCSV = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option('header',True) \
    .schema(schema) \
    .option('maxFilesPerTrigger',1) \
    .csv("stocks")

# Generate running average price
avgStockPrice = dfCSV.groupBy("stock").avg()

 # Start running the query that prints the running averages to the console
query = avgStockPrice \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

When I put in more than one file it calculates over all the files as expected, running a batch for each file. But then if I add any more files, a batch is triggered, but the results are exactly the same, not changing no matter how many new files I add.

I tried changing the avg to count to see if I was just getting an average price from the random function generating the files but I got the same result. The row count increased for each new file for the initial files in the folder but did not budge when adding more files. A computation was triggered, but no new results.

Using Ubuntu 18.04, python 3.7.10, spark 3.0.1, pyspark (jupyter notebook).

Comment: Could that be that the values you `avg` give the same result because that's their average? Could you use `count`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  The count didn't update either.